# execute a function to start app

Tags: symfony

I have a idea table, with a date field I want to check if the idea has expired.

If the date of  the idea if less than today the state is ok, else the state of idea is expire.

Where I have to write this function, If I have to check all the ideas when I start the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a cron job to me. Create a simple script that set the state of your ideas based on the date, and run that each night.

Answer (score 0):

You can just provide your class an `isExpired()` method:

```
public function isExpired()
{

  $today = new \DateTime;

  return $this -> date < $today;

}
```